# How to get params in controller from collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to handle the data from collection_select in the view :

```
    <%= form_for(:group, :url => {:action => 'update', :group_id => @group.id}) do |f| %>       
            <th>New member</th>
            <td><%= f.collection_select(:members, @users, :id, :first_name) %></td>
            <%= submit_tag("Update Group") %>
    <% end %>
```

but i'm not able to get it in the controller :

```
member_id = params[:member]
puts member_id.inspect
```

inspect result in the console :

> nil

but when I get an error, i can see the member_id exists :

```
undefined method `each' for "1":String
     "utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"GxCd==",
     "group"=>{"name"=>"G7",
     "members"=>"1"},
     "commit"=>"Update Group",
     "group_id"=>"4"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your form has a `:event` and your `params` showing that they are coming from `group`. Did you posted the wrong code?

Comment: And also this line `puts desc.inspect` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you add the value of `params` to your question please?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the error you posted, you can see that `params` is the following hash;

```
{
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"GxCd==",
    "group"=> {
        "name"=>"G7",
        "members"=>"1"
    },
    "commit"=>"Update Group",
    "group_id"=>"4"
}
```

`params[:group]` is a nested hash, so to access your members key it would be `params[:group][:members]`

Comment: No problem. Remember to accept (green tick) one of the answers if you're happy.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `member_id` you have to call:

```
params[:group][:members] # = "1"
```